# Accessing a Parent Property in props.children

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a React class that has some elements that are not known ahead of time, which is a natural give away for me to use props.children. These props.children require access to a variable that is set in the parent (ParentComponent), so to give them access, this is what I do:

```
{ React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {parentComponentVariable: value}) }
```

I have a special use case for ParentComponent, in fact, it is never directly used but used for composing specialized variations of itself, which is where the children are passed in.

Effectively, the classes that leverage ParentComponent look like this:

```
SpecializedParentComponent = (props) => { 
 <ParentComponent {...props}>
{props.parentComponentVariable && (<h1> Render this conditional h1 tag</h1>)}
 </ParentComponent>
}
```

SpecializedParentComponent is what gets rendered, and it effectively renders ParentComponent, as I have indicated in the sample code.

However, this does not work, as parentComponentVariable is never available as a prop inside of SpecializedParentComponentVariable. The above actually causes the code to crash, since it's a conditionally rendered child, it actually is passed in as undefined.

What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
    React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        parentComponentVariable: value
      })
    })
```

Comment: thanks, this worked! Can you elaborate why a map function did work whereas just the React.cloneElement did not? 

Additionally, I noticed something, parentComponentVariable is either false or true. It works fine when it is set to true, but when it is false, it breaks again.

Comment: Because when it is false, based on your condition, it would be
<ParentComponent> </ParentComponent> and hence it will break.

Comment: great, do you have a suggestion on how I can avoid that?